# Concatenating video files(with audio) and mixing in an audio voiceover

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm concatenating 4 video files with `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" out.mp4`

I have another audio file(audio.mp3) that needs to be mixed in with the video as a background music. How can I specify that in the above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i audio.mp3 \
  -filter_complex
    "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[outv][outa];
    [outa][4]amix=duration=first[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" out.mp4
```

Comment: I have a followup question. When the file 3.mp4 does not have an audio, it gives me audio stream not found. How can I create an audio stream that will have audio for 1.mp4 + 2.mp4 + delay for the duration of 3.mp4 + 4.mp4

Comment: After `-i audio.mp3`, add `-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc`, and replace `[3:a:0]` with `[5:a]`